# how to insert item at the beginning of a associative array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am currently trying to group my data based on date and some name. Here is my code

```
    $data = [];
    foreach($allmatches as $d){
       $name = $d['div']['divisionName'];
       $data[$d['playingDate']][$name][]=$d;
       $data[$d['playingDate']]['day']=$d['day'];
       $data[$d['playingDate']]['month']=$d['month'];
       $data[$d['playingDate']]['isToday']=$d['isToday'];
    }
    return $data;

OUTPUT 
======
2018-09-18: {
  Elitserien: [+],
  day: "18",
  month: "Sep",
  isToday: true,
  Division 2: [+],
  Division 5: [+]
},
```

Current out put starts with `Elitserien` but I want to achieve `Division 5` at the beginning..

To help further, here is a picture of the current data 
[image]

I want to insert the new element always at the beginning of the array. How can I do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Use `array_unshift()`

Comment: is it possible with associative array? Could you give me an example please? Many thanks

Comment: You are trying to add at the beginning in "first-level" only, right?

Comment: Yes, at the first level of grouping the array.

Comment: array_ushift doesn't help me to group elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an associative array, you need to use `array_merge` to prepend the series data (i.e. data indexed by `$name` to the beginning of the `$data[$d['playingDate']]` array. This code will do what you want. Note that I've put the series code at the end to avoid having to check for `$data[$d['playingDate']]` being set as well as `$data[$d['playingDate']][$name]`.

```
$data = [];
foreach($allmatches as $d){
   $name = $d['div']['divisionName'];
   $data[$d['playingDate']]['day']=$d['day'];
   $data[$d['playingDate']]['month']=$d['month'];
   $data[$d['playingDate']]['isToday']=$d['isToday'];
   if (!isset($data[$d['playingDate']][$name])) $data[$d['playingDate']] = array_merge(array($name => array()), $data[$d['playingDate']]);
   $data[$d['playingDate']][$name][]=$d;
}
```

I've created a small [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/C45vQ)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `+` operator:

```
$data = [];
foreach($allmatches as $d){

   $name = $d['div']['divisionName'];

   // Prepare a temp array
   $temp = array();
   $temp[$name][]   = $d;
   $temp['day']     = $d['day'];
   $temp['month']   = $d['month'];
   $temp['isToday'] = $d['isToday'];

   // Add to the beginning of $data array (first-level)
   $data = array($d['playingDate'] => $temp) + $data;
}
return $data;
```

Comment: Nope, it simply changes my original structure.

Comment: @sadek Without sample data and corresponding expected output, it is now difficult to figure out what you need!

Comment: I understand, but it extremely difficult to rewrite such a big long code to produce same things :(

Comment: @sadek Can you prepare a [Rextester Fiddle](https://rextester.com/l/php_online_compiler) - you can put the relevant code there; and add that to question instead of posting images (ppl would downvote for images)

Comment: Unfortuently array size is bigger so no online editor is supporting and tried to reduce and make it small still array looks bigger. Anyways thank you for the help @Madhur Bhaiya

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I think the general consensus is not to use rextester any more: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375602/rextester-has-officially-been-hacked-where-do-we-go-from-here

Comment: @Nick I don't use meta. Thanks for informing. What's the alternative ?

Answer (score -2):

`array_unshift()` function will fix your problem.